# pyftpdlib only one usage for each socket address

Tags: python, sockets, ftp-server

I am using python 2.7.2 on a windows 7 machine.

my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def dummy_ftp_server(local_interface, username, password, homedir, perms): 
    from pyftpdlib.authorizers import DummyAuthorizer
    from pyftpdlib.handlers import FTPHandler
    from pyftpdlib.servers import FTPServer

    authorizer = DummyAuthorizer()
    authorizer.add_user(username, password, homedir, perm=perms)

    handler = FTPHandler
    handler.authorizer = authorizer

    server = FTPServer((local_interface, 21), handler)
    server.serve_forever()      

process = Process(target=dummy_ftp_server, args=('127.0.0.1', 'user', 'pass', "C:/path/test", 'elradfmw'))
process.start()
```

when trying to run the ftp server using `multiprocessing.process` i get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\path\test_ftp.py", line 18, in dummy_ftp_server
>       server = FTPServer((local_interface, 21), handler)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyftpdlib\servers.py", line 145, in **init**
>       self._af = self.bind_af_unspecified(address_or_socket)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyftpdlib\ioloop.py", line 733, in bind_af_unspecified
>       raise socket.error(err)
>   error: [Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

if i run it without using `multiprocessing.process` by using

```
dummy_ftp_server('127.0.0.1', 'user', 'pass', "C:/path/test", 'elradfmw')
```

it works fine.

on a linux machine i dont have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run multiple ftp servers on the same ip address with the same port.
That is what the error is telling you.

It could be you already have something running on 127.0.0.1:21

check in a console with netstat -an